# How do I get the entire contents of a web page in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, web, minecraft

Simple question, how do I get the contents of http://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=somethinghere? I will have a list of usernames in a text file, and I want to go through all of them and see if they've paid or not. The contents of this web page will either be true or false. No html, nothing but "true" or "false". How do I get that content? I don't need anything fancy. This is the first time I've dealt with web based stuff in Java.

Comment: -1? Why? I'm new to Java, I couldn't find anything on Google relating to this.

Comment: *"Simple question.."* "What is the meaning of life?" is  a simple question - it is the answer that is tougher.  (But no, I am not the down-voter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually asking how to perform HTTP GET using java API. Here is the code snippet.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=somethinghere");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   // parse your content here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpClient.html) or spring [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) can do the job.

Something like that with spring `RestTemplate`:

```
public class Foo {
    /** 
     * Production HTTP end point.
     */ 
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp";

    /**
     * {@link RestTemplate} for HTTP access.
     */
    @Autowire
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public Foo() {
        this.baseUrl = BASE_URL;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for testing purposes.
     *
     * @param baseUrl HTTP end-point url to use.
     * @param restTemplate {@link RestTemplate} to use (a mock probably).
     */
    protected Foo(final String baseUrl, final RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Check if user has paid.
     *
     * @param userName Name of the user to check.
     * @return true if user has paid
     */
    public boolean hasPaid(final String userName) {
        if (userName == null) {
            return false;
        }

        final String result = restTemplate.getForObject(this.baseUrl + 
            "?user={user}", String.class, userName);

        return Boolean.valueOf(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to take a look at those tomorrow. I'll look around for some examples too.